# What are the 'protos' in TF Object Detection?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I am struggling to understand what are the 'protos' in TF Object Detection?

Why do we need them here?

Also, while setting up the TF API we need to download and compile protocol buffers.

There is also a 'protos' folder when one downloads the object detection module - could anyone please explain me what are those and what is the relationship between them?

Comment: The tensorflow api uses Protobufs to configure model and training parameters. what is protobuf? sourced from google "Protocol buffers are Google's language-neutral, platform-neutral, extensible mechanism for serializing structured data – think XML, but smaller, faster, and simpler. You define how you want your data to be structured once, then you can use special generated source code to easily write and read your structured data to and from a variety of data streams and using a variety of languages. 
 "https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers

Comment: Welcome to DSSE; please try to make your titles succinct and to the point - titles are not the place for "pleasantries" (edited).

Answer (score 0):

"Protos" is short protocol buffer (a.k.a., protobuf). Protocol buffers are Google's language-neutral, platform-neutral, extensible mechanism for serializing structured data. It is the way TensorFlow stores models on disk.